# Product CSV file not exporting from admin in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, export, importexport

When we export Procuct Csv from admin side.
Then csv not export.
We get error

> There is no data for the export.

Any one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because you may be exporting parent categories and it may not contain any products. Try exporting from the child categories where products are assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento queue:consumer:start exportProcessor
```

This command initiates the export processor consumer, which is responsible for handling product exports through the Magento message queue system.